# Icomoon font renders strange in Safari 11

Tags: ios, svg, fonts, safari, cross-browser

Icomoon font shows up strange in latest Safari. It has unexpected 'holes' in the filled areas.
For example:
[zoomed in icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCfe.png)

[this should be filled with color as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Qxi.png)

These icons look good in all other browsers. So, not sure where to dig with this problem.

UPDATE:
Also looks good on Sierra and Safari 10.1
[Safari 10.1 icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ckoz.png)

Thanks in advance.
PS/ My first StackOverflow question ever ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out - the issue was caused by incorrect source svg. It should contain no strokes, only fills, and fill-rule="nonzero" - to be correctly converted by icomoon app to a icon font.